# I'm having trouble connecting my TV to my computer

Tags: display, desktop

when I try to connect my computer to the TV and mirror the screens I'm starting to see problems, especially after I do a restart. Problems like: the resolution seems to be low, everything is in big size. On one screen the cursor is visible and on the other it is not. Sometimes I can't even open the setting.
I'm really frustrated with this problem. I have an AMD GPU and I tried installing drivers and trying different settings with the AMD control setting but nothing worked. 
Please help me solve this problem. I just want to be able to duplicate the two displays.

P.S: I don't have problems with either screens or cables because I was able to do it without any problems  on Windows and Ubuntu.